# How to configure incremental refresh for table that doesn't show native query?

Tags: powerbi

I have a large fact table.

Until the last step where I merge it with another table, I can see native query. Only after the merge it stops showing the native query.

This mean that if I configure incremental refresh on this table, then it will still perform a full load. Because the pre-requisite for incremental refresh is that it should show native query.

What is the solution/workaround to this? For example: Say I remove the last (merge) step, and now it shows me native query and so say I configure incremental refresh for this. Then, can I create a new table that references this table and perform the merge operation using this table so that all the steps prior to merge (referenced from original table) happen as incremental load, where as merge happens non-incrementally. Is this possible? I think not because reference doesn't mean reuse and so it will fire a fresh query for the new table (including all steps from the referenced source table).

Comment: How do you source your fact table? SQL?

Comment: Via sql server connection. Not explicit SQL

Comment: Did you think to put sql query inside powerquery (M)? May be merge via sql statement is more simple way?

Comment: If the source is sql query then can the query fold?

Comment: What do you mean by query fold?

Comment: Query folding means the final step of power query must be able to generate native sql query.